# Attach additional functionality to parent controller in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a dropdown **element** directive to display in essence a styled dropdown list with additional capabilities.

My dropdown controller has a function called `openDropdownItems` that get's executed when the list should be displayed.

Then I also have another **attribute** directive called `setInViewWhen` that provides an expression when the element should be scrolled into view when condition is true.

```
<x set-in-view-when="something.item === selectedItem">
```

This is just an example of some *X* element with my attribute directive applied.

The thing is that I would like my dropdown list items (LIs namely) to have this directive on them so when user navigates over them using a keyboard, it would automatically scroll them in view when they get passed visible viewport. Whether these items are displayed within a scrollable container or as a whole in a list longer than the browser viewport isn't really relevant.

The main idea is for scrolling to follow dropdown list selection. Whether that should scroll the main window.

### The problem

I can make my `setInViewWhen` directive completely independent but that means that I would have to search for the closest scrollable container whenever condition changes on an item. This seems to be quite a bit of processing that I would like to avoid to repeat (I need to traverse the DOM upwards, checking each node's calculated stylesheet property OverflowY + some additional checks.

This basically seems redundant because whenever I get the closest scrolling ancestor all sibling elements with the same directive could reuse the calculation result.

#### Question 1

How can I share this knowledge between sibling directives? If I was to fire an event I could not know whether receivers are siblings or not without any additional processing.

#### Question 2

Instead of checking for scrollable container every time when my directive's condition becomes true I could theoretically change dropdown parent's `openDropdownItems` to first complete it's original execution an then also execute the scrollability check and use the result of it along with my directive's condition.
I can gain access to dropdown's controller in my directive via directive `requires` property and adjust it in the post-link phase.

But this also means that I couldn't use my directive outside of dropdown which I would like to as it is a generally usable directive I could attach on several elements in my app to scroll elements into view under certain conditions.

### What would you suggest how to do this?

Comment: Some thoughts/observations: (1) For Q1, there is no direct way for sibling directives to communicate with each other. I usually create a wrapper parent directive to relay the messages. (2) I *guess* the condition `something.item === selectedItem` introduces a watch; for a list of select items this can be many watches and detrimental to performance. I would rather have a single watch in the parent of the LIs and add the "scroll into view" logic there.

Comment: (3) With point 2 in mind, you could still have a standalone `setInViewWhen` directive (seems useful) *and* have the controller of your `X`-select replacement directive share code with it. E.g. create a service with common functionality, create an angular value containing a JS "class" and have the controller of both the `setInViewWhen` and `X` directives extend from it (or other solutions).

Comment: (4) Rel to Q2: While the children could require their parent and change a method in it (this technique is even endorsed by Angular, see ng-model and custom controls), there would be many children changing it, which could lead to a mess...

Comment: Of course. Each directive has its own watch that does something along the lines `$scope.$watch($parse($attrs.setInViewWhen)($scope)`, ...)`, You're very true about (4) that the function itself would get wrapped many many times. Bad idea. Might be that (3) is the way to go to actually create two directives: one related to dropdown and the other standalone. But instead of creating a service I can easily create a base controller of both as I'm using TypeScript and then extend child classes.

Comment: Yeap, base controller is great.

Comment: @nikos why don't you put all this in an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum up the comments:

- For Question 1, there is no direct way for sibling directives to communicate with each other. I usually create a wrapper parent directive to relay the messages.
- As per the comments, the condition `something.item === selectedItem` introduces a watch; for a list of select items this can be many watches and detrimental to performance. Even if it doesn't occur now, it is a trap and someone may be lured into using this for a long list of items in the future. I would rather have a single watch in the parent of the `<li>`s and add the "scroll into view" logic there.
- With the previous point in mind, you could still have a standalone `setInViewWhen` directive (seems useful) and have the controller of your `X`-select replacement directive share code with it. E.g.:

  - a service containing the common functionality,
  - an angular value containing a base class (Typescript or JS) and have the controller of both the `setInViewWhen` and `X` directives extend from it
  - or any other solution that is convenient for your case
- Related to Question 2: The children could require their parent and change a method in it (this technique is even endorsed by Angular, see `ng-model` and custom controls where they override `ngModel.$render()` by replacing it). If you do that however, there would be many children changing the method of the parent, which could lead to a mess.